# All Links part of Global or Left navigation are not visible to Read only access users in SPS2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, navigation, links

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Users part of Read access group are facing issue, they cant view:

a) Top Navigation visible with no all links, same for left navigation.

I tried removing the Read permission and adding it again, no good.

Therefore, as a test later upgraded from Read permission to Full permission, still the same. Please suggest what best can be done to get users access Intranet homepage with Read permission.

Troubleshooting performed:
Logged as the full sharepoint2013 administrator

a) Seattle.master is set as default site & system master page.

b) Left navigation is using managed navigation, just as the global navigation.

c) I tried disabling security trimming & audience targeting , but no good.

d) added the user to the group that has read access and also shared the site with the user. Still cant see all navigation links either in Global (TOP) or Left navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using managed navigation instead of structural make sure that the **Navigation Node Type** is a **Simple Link or Header**, the Term driven menu items are not visible to users with only read permissions.

You can find more info about it here:
http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2016/05/12/metadata-navigation-is-not-visible-to-users-with-read-permissions/

Comment: that`s a goog piece of information